# _.difference but allow duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I'm trying to find the difference of two arrays but duplicates are allowed in the array and so I want to only remove them one at a time.

This is probably easier to show with an example. The `_.difference` function works like this:

```
_.difference([1, 1, 2], [1]); // returns [2]
```

But I would like to know if there is a function (preferably in underscore) that would instead do this:

```
_.difference2([1, 1, 2], [1]); // returns [1, 2]
_.difference2([1, 1, 2], [1, 1]); // returns [2]
```

And if there is not already a way to do this what would be an efficient way to make a mixin that does?

Answer (score 2):

This mixin I came up with works.. but open to suggestions on how to improve it:

```
_.mixin({
    remove: function(base, toRemove) {
        var ret = [];
        toRemove = _.clone(toRemove);

        _.each(base, function(elem) {
            var i = _.indexOf(toRemove, elem);
            if(i < 0) {
                ret.push(elem);
            } else {
                toRemove[i] = undefined;
            }
        });

        return ret;
    }
});

_.remove([1, 1, 2], [1]); // returns [1, 2]
_.remove([1, 1, 2], [1, 1]); // returns [2]
```

Comment: +1, but I'd recommend a more descriptive name. It currently even collides with the [lodash `remove` function](http://lodash.com/docs#remove)

Comment: Any suggestion for what this would be called?

Comment: Not sure. The current `difference` function uses the arrays to represent sets, while you are looking for `multiset` or `array` or `list` difference.